# Can I access the documents using another app if that app has iCloud access (similar to dropbox)?

Tags: ios5, icloud

I have uploaded PDF files(iCloud enabled )from one app of my iPad. How do I access that document from iCloud by using another ipad application(IOS) that have access to iCloud also.

Answer (score 0):

Mark it as "shared" in iCloud.